# htaccess redirect all traffic to http (non-ssl)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am trying to avoid using SSL altogether, even if requested.

I got this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.domain.net/$1 [R,L]
```

but it does not seems to work.

It is a on shared hosting (if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Just letting people know. I'm searching through answers trying to solve this problem myself.

Comment: @CriketX: Post a separate question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.